# Detecting directions using Convolutional neural networks

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, object-detection, convolutional-neural-network, object-recognition

I am working on a task where I have to detect damages on the vehicles and exactly where the damage has occurred. So I have to not only detect the damage on the door but also mentioned which door(front left,rear right,etc). Is it possible to not only detect the objects but the direction of the objects as well using Convolutional Neural Networks. Are there any implementation of tasks similar to this?